# what should be a good bibliography for deep learning in 2020

Tags: deep-learning

What should be a good bibliography for having a good overview of deep learning (on image/signal processing) in 2020 ?

Comment: This is very broad question! What in particular are you working on? (Don’t say image or signal processing)

Comment: Yes this is a very broad question. And on this very broad question, what is for you, by example, the 2 best books to read in 2020 to be up to date on state-of-art. You can see the question also like this : if you have to read one book on "Deep Learning" in 2020, which one ?

Comment: While it may no longer be "state of the art" being written in 2016, https://www.deeplearningbook.org/ is a good place to get an overview of different deep learning ideas